# JQuery ForEach loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey, how can I say the following

Foreach  tag in my table, when someone clicks it I want to run a function

so something like:

```
ForEachTag.click  
(  
    function (e)   
    {  
    }  
)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a table like this:

```
<table id='test'>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
    <td>Hi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">test1</a></td>
    <td>Hi</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The most basic selector is going to look like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    alert('test!');
    return false;
});
```

This is simply binding something to *all* the links in the document. Want more control?

```
$('#test').find('a').click(function(e) {
    alert('test!');
    return false;
});
```

Which is essentially saying: "find me all the `<a>` elements inside the element with id of `test` and bind this click handler to it" - jQuery is so powerful because it handles sets of objects this way.

This is just the tip of the iceberg, though! You can get much more in-depth. What if you only want to bind the `<a>` elements that appear in the 1st `<td>` relative to the `<tr>`? No problem:

```
$('#test').find('td:nth-child(1) a').click(function(e) {
    alert('test');
    return false;
});
```

Although jQuery does have an `each` function that lets you iterate through a set of elements, when it comes to binding events you will rarely need it. jQuery loves sets and will do anything you ask it to to a set of elements if it makes any sense.

Comment: $("#test").find("a") == $("#test a")

Comment: @Josh: I'm not a big fan of having everything in the same selector, plus I felt using the find syntax would be more expressive of what is actually happening.

Comment: Boo.  The purpose of jQuery's selector engine is to emulate CSS.  Additionally, chaining another call to the find function is inefficient (unjustifiably so).  I think you just wanted to squeeze a mini jQuery tutorial into the answer, which I guess is just fine.

Comment: Actually, chaining another call is more efficient most of the time. While jQuery lets you put everything in one selector, it has to go through a complicated parsing logic to try and determine the rules. The simpler you make them by separating them into function calls not only makes your code more expressive as to what is going on but makes jQuery have to do less work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how you want to do it. Basically, you have two options:

1. Add a click listener for each tag matching your selector
2. Add a click listener of the parent container, and figure out the element that was clicked inside the click handler function (event delegation)

To add the same click-listener to multiple tags, do this:

```
$(selectorForElements).click(function (e) {
    // Click handling code here.
    // e is the event object
    // this inside the handler refers to the element that was clicked.
});
```

To use [event delegation](http://lab.distilldesign.com/event-delegation), do something like this:

```
$(selectorForParentElement).click(function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target());
    // Checked if we clicked the "correct" element, else traverse
    // up the DOM tree until we find the parent element we ARE interested in.
    if(!target.is(whatYouAreInterestedIn)) {
        target = target.parent(whatYouAreInterestedIn).eq(0);
    }
    // Your click handler for the target goes here
});
```

When possible it is better to use event delegation since it binds fewer listeners and thus consumes less memory and increases execution speed, especially on older browsers. You can read some about event delegation here:

- http://lab.distilldesign.com/event-delegation
- http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/eventdelegation/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Comment: Instead of messing with target, live() is much more concise and uses event delegation...

Comment: That seems to be the case yes.. I'm coming from Prototype. I still don't quite understand how it works from the docs.. Does it internally find the parent containing all elements matched by the selector to do the event delegation? Or does it always put itself on the body-tag?

Comment: I haven't checked the source code, but presumably it would be on the body tag, as it has no way of knowing where other elements might pop up down the road (as it is advertised mostly as a way to bind dynamically added elements).